# What is the first argument of next() in express js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

It seems you can pass an argument to `next()`, usually an error?

How is this used? How do I access that error?

eg:

```js
router.get('/my-url', function(req, res, next) {
  next(new Error('my error');
});
```

Comment: The docs have a whole page on handling errors: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

Comment: i was looking for docs on next() which i still cant find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass an **error** to `next()`, if will forward it to the error handler.

An error handler is a middleware defined with 4 inputs, where first input is an **error**.

So, you need to define an error handler in order to catch the error that is passed with `next()`:

```js
// Error handler
app.use((error, req, res, next) =>

  console.log('ERROR:', error)

);
```

Comment: can this be added to a router, instead of from the app? I mean using `router.get()` instead of `app.use()`, since I want to just handle errors for a specific group of routes? it doesnt seem to be catching it

Comment: You should define it after your router... Maybe you defined it before your router?